# Error en Epplus

Tags: vb.net, epplus

Antes de todo quiero decirles que soy novato en esto.
Al trabajar con **Epplus** en  ***.net*** obtengo este error:

> ERROR INESPERADO
>   System.IO.FileLoadException: 
>   Could not load file or assembly ´EPPlus, Version4.1.0.0, Cultureneutral, PublicKeyTokenea159fdaa78159a1´ 
>   or one of its dependencies. The located assembly´s manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
>    (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) File name: ´EPPlus,
>    Version4.1.0.0, Cultureneutral, PublicKeyTokenea159fdaa78159a1´

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Bajaste todos los paquetes correctamente?

Comment: Prueba a quitar la referencia y volver a añadirla